# Creating user defined function for checking prime no in python

Tags: python, pycharm

```
num=int(input("enter the no: "))
def Prime(num):

    """Check whether a no is prime or not"""
    for i in range(2,num):

        if num%i==0:
            print(num," is not prime no")
            break
        else:
            print(num,"is prime no")
            break

print(Prime(num))
```

While the output comes like this

```
    enter the no: 45
    45 is prime no
    None
```

What wrong with this code to check prime no and also why 'None' gets printed in the output. How do I use return here.
The output come correct for some no like 97 but comes out wrong here for 45.
Your suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: You're only checking for divisibility by 2.  Whether that's true or false, you execute a `break`, and the loop does not proceed to any higher possible divisors.

Comment: If I remove the break then it iterate over the range upto num and returns output as prime and not prime for the no 45

Comment: How will i iterate over the range and print the output accordingly? Suppose if i=2 then it will go to else statement and print no is prime and it will not iterate over the range.

Answer (score 0):

```
num=int(input("enter the no: "))

def Prime(num):
    flag = False
    if num > 1:
        for i in range(2, num):
            if (num % i) == 0:
                flag = True
                break

    if flag:
        print(num, "is not a prime number")
    else:
        print(num, "is a prime number")
        
Prime(num)
```

Comment: Is flag necessary here. If not using flag how would it be. Kindly explain why flag = False and the work of (return flag).Lastly the statements after return can we just write the else  and print the output.

Comment: flag is not necessary here, but easy to understand. Can be done in many different ways for example using counters or directly printing as not prime when the if condition is true.
Have edited the return part to make it easy to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but one thing how do I use the return statement here we know return statement returns a value. And also without using flag how do I use the return statement.

Comment: If you want to use return statement, you will need to return a value (most probably boolean in this case). You can return true or false directly without assigning it to the variable "flag" as well